# "SIP registration failed with status=503 (Connection refused)" with PJSUA2

Tags: android, openssl, sip, voip, pjsip

I succefuly build pjsip library with OpenSSL. Now how can I configure TLS transport using pjsua2? After this:

```
TlsConfig tlsConfig = new TlsConfig();
sipTpConfig.setTlsConfig(tlsConfig);

try {
    ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, ipTpConfig);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Log tells, that "!SIP TLS listener is ready for incoming connections". But when I added new account, SIP registration failed with status=503(Connection refused). Here is asterisk configuration:

```
icesupport=yes
avpf=yes
qualify=yes
encryption=yes
dtlsenable=yes
dtlsverify = no
dtlsrekey = 60
dtlscafile = /var/lib/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
dtlscertfile = /var/lib/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlssetup = actpass
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need a DNS SVR record; see [Resolving A records for domains without SRV records fails](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.pjsip/7242) on the PJSIP forums.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the port that is not used. You can configure this after you instantiate TransportConfig.

```
 TlsConfig tlsConfig;
    tlsConfig.port = 6000;
```

It could also be your sip registration is not going through. Make sure that you are adding sip in front of the sipuserid like this:
"sip:555@s444.com;transport=tcp"